# Search Console is reporting many server (5xx) errors for strange URLs

Tags: server, error

Google Search Console is reporting many server errors for my site. Currently, there are 242 affected 'pages', but this number keeps increasing. When I look at the URLs, most aren't real pages of my site. They look like URLs with spam injected into them (forgive my ignorance!).

In addition to the URLs with spam in them, there are other URLs that are real but incomplete. For example, the last character of the URL might be missing, or the last word. Or sometimes the URL is for an attachment page.

Does anyone know what is going on and how I can fix these issues, please?

[image]

[image]

[image]